# How to set row width by container width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my file I have this structure:

```
<div class="container" style="width:1000px;  border: 1px dashed #000">
    <div class="row-fluid" >
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid green">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5" style="border:1px solid red">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The main problem is that the border of container is bigger that two colums

[image]

Comment: Post your CSS, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: There is only default bootstrap css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the default for Bootstrap is a 12 width grid.  Your two divs fill only 11 width (6 + 5), whereas the container defaults to 12, so the last column shows as blank space.
Change your second column to have 6 width.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid red">
```